# Excel VBA - Can I assign part of a Cell Value to a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a date in a particular cell (B3) - Date - 12/03/2016. I am trying to assign only the Year part of the date, i.e. 2016 to a variable. Is it possible?

Comment: `var=Year(Cell(3,2).Value2)` should do the job

Comment: Thanks, how can i do the same to extract part value of the Cell if it's in Text

Comment: I think that should work but if it doesn't you can try `var= RIGHT( Trim(Cell(3,2).Value2),4)`

Comment: This gives me an Compile error highlighting 'Cell' saying Sub or Function not defined.

Comment: Oops sorry it should be `Cells` and not `Cell`

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
Dim yourvariable%
yourvariable = int(mid([B3],7,4))
```

or

```
Dim yourvariable%
yourvariable = int(Right([B3],4))
```

or

```
Dim yourvariable%
yourvariable = year(cdate([B3]))
```

Comment: I got rid of my comment too soon. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim v As Variant

    v = Split(Range("B3").Text, "/")(2)
    MsgBox v
End Sub
```

[image]